# file_get_contents('php://input') returning empty string with a PUT request

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-8.5

After moving one of our websites from Linux with Apache to Windows with IIS (8.5) running PHP 5.6 via FastCGI, we've run into the problem that `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns an empty string for PUT requests.

I've created the following test:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>POST:</h2>
    <div id="post"></div>

    <h2>PUT:</h2>
    <div id="put"></div>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: '?',
            data: 'Working',
            type: 'POST'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $('#post').html(response || 'Not working');
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '?',
            data: 'Working',
            type: 'PUT'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $('#put').html(response || 'Not working');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which results in:

> POST:
>
> Working
>
> PUT:
>
> Not working

What could be causing this?

Comment: maybe conflicts with IIS WebDAV-module. Also check 'Handler Mappings' options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the problem is caused by the Helicon Ape module (a module for supporting Apache .htaccess and .htpasswd configuration files). 
Removing this module fixes the problem, but I still don't know why it would interfere with PUT requests. I guess I'll have to post a topic on their forum with this issue.

Comment: PUT for restful request.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I am facing the same problem! I can't still figure it out!